# APIM Unable to access service in subnet(AKS)

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-aks, azure-virtual-network

I am trying to integrate APIM and AKS. where APIM will be public facing and AKS will be inside the VNet. I have followed this article https://pumpingco.de/blog/control-ingress-to-aks-with-azure-api-management and did the following.

1. created a new subnet for the apim and new one for the api service
2. updated the APIM vnet settings as external and map it to the newly created subnet.

after that I have deployed the service in AKS, the service is getting the IP of the api service subnet. when I did port forward I am able to access the site. but from the APIM if I enter the details of the swagger its saying unable to access. I am new to APIM, is there any way I can try to ping or something like to make sure that its accessible ?

Here is the kubetctl command returns

```
NAME         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP    PORT(S)       
todosvc      LoadBalancer   10.0.196.84    10.0.1.4       8002:30409/TCP   19m
```

Here is the Network.

[image]

Update: I am able to access the endpoint when I enter it directly. I think the problem is with importing the swagger.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a mistake from my end. I was entering the swagger url, instead it should be path for json file. for e.g for our .net core application instead of entering http://url/swagger.index.html it should be https://url/swagger/v1/swagger.json

or we can import swagger file like json or yaml.