# APIM unable to connect to service deployed in AKS

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-api-management

We have private AKS cluster create under a virtual network (MC resource group). We also have an APIM crated under the same virtual network. A few services are deployed in K8 and exposed via internal loadbalancer of K8. when we do kubectl get svc get a cluster IP and an external IP.
I've used the external IP to connect to APIM. but its failing with the following error

> Unable to download specified file. Please ensure the URL is valid and the file is publicly accessible.

Comment: How did you configure APIM into the vnet?

Comment: Which URL you're accessing?

Answer (score 0):

The error of `unable to download ...` might be from the URL of the IP address, because when the field is filled with a azure blob storage url, no errors should come.

[image]

I think you can try to add api instance by uploading json file from localhost.

In the Network Security Groups, you should also add a new Inbound Security Rule.

Change the label in the Source service tag by selecting Service Tag from the dropdown menu that appears. There is an option for ApiManagement in this dropdown.

You must select an IP address from the drop-down list and type the API Management Service's IP address.

For more information to resolve this error, refer [here](https://www.puresourcecode.com/tools/azure-tools/how-to-use-an-azure-api-management-service/#h-wrong-selection) and also this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64603173/apim-unable-to-access-service-in-subnetaks).